# Convert Bitmap to Integer (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String lenguajeProgramacion[]=new String[]{"Java","PHP","Python","JavaScript","Ruby","C",
            "Go","Perl","Pascal"};

    private Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.php,
            R.drawable.python,
            R.drawable.javascript,
            R.drawable.ruby,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.go,
            R.drawable.perl,
            R.drawable.pascal
    };
    private ListView lista;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LenguajeListAdapter adapter=new LenguajeListAdapter(this,lenguajeProgramacion,imgid);
        lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mi_lista);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String Slecteditem= lenguajeProgramacion[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And i have this:

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

I need convert this bitmap to Integer to can use the program.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by Integer? Bitmap is Bitmap. Integer is Integer.

Comment: Can you be clearer what your question/problem is? Is can see no link between your question and the code.

Comment: The problem is i have an image in a bitmap, i get this in my database 

bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conimagen.getInputStream());              I need to show a lot of images, so i am going to have a lot of bitmap. To show the images i have an adapter where images are in Interger[], and for this i need convert o another solution to can show my images

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access the id of the image (which is an `int`) as you are doing with others like `R.drawable.php`, you can just use `R.mipmap.ic_launcher` and use it to get it in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works, the problem is this other bitmap:

URL urlimagen = new URL(IMAGENES + alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("rutaimagen"));

HttpURLConnection conimagen = (HttpURLConnection) urlimagen.openConnection();

conimagen.connect();

*bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conimagen.getInputStream());*